# Why my divs are not one in the left and the other in the right in the same lane?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put in the same div, that the text of "Bienvenido a TPV Santander" appears on the left, and the red button appears on the right, in the same line, however it goes down. I leave my code here. Is there something you are doing wrong?

```
 <div id="divBotoneraMapaGestiones" style="text-align: left;width: 100%;display: block;" class="singular_botone">
    <div class="singular_h1" style="display: inline-block;width: 48%;padding: 1%;">Bienvenido a <span class="singular_textorojo">TPV Santander</span></div>
    <a href="#" id="200TPVMapaGestiones" class="singular_button w-button" style="display: inline-block;width: 48%;padding: 1%;">Consulta el mapa de <br><span class="singular_textobotonpeque">gestiones</span></a>
    <div class="clear" style="clear: both;"></div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U can use this example

```css
.row {
 display: flex; 
 justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="left">
  <div class="singular_h1">Bienvenido a <span class="singular_textorojo">TPV Santander</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
  <a href="#" id="200TPVMapaGestiones" class="singular_button w-button">Consulta el mapa de <br><span class="singular_textobotonpeque">gestiones</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```